# Manipulate bookmarks of pdf files without expanding it?

Tags: pdf, foxit-reader

I have downloaded many PDF files, some without bookmarks. Usually I add bookmarks for these PDF files manually, with Foxit PDF reader

But once I add the bookmark, the bookmark of the PDF file would unfold from top to bottom the next time I open it.

So how do I add/edit bookmarks of the PDF file without unfolding it? Is there a way to do this with Foxit reader, or will I have to use another program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link tools in **[PDF-Xchangeviewer](http://www.docu-track.com/home/prod_user/PDF-XChange_Tools/pdfx_viewer)** work just fine for me.

*a [free and portable version](http://www.docu-track.com/download/PDFX_Vwr_Port.zip) is available.*

Comment: you're more than welcome.